# making a pop up style view on iPhone with arrows objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I having the follow pop up and I want to make the edges curved. 
[image]

Using this code.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);

CGFloat baseWidth = 15.0;
CGFloat height = 10.0;

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width / 2.0 - baseWidth / 2.0, height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width / 2.0 + baseWidth / 2.0, height);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, height);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

How can I curve the edges?

Comment: `CGContextAddArcToPoint` or `CGContextAddCurveToPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Core Graphics and drawing those straight lines right up to each other in the screen shot above. To be able to draw curves you need to add in some calls to `CGContectAddArcToPoint`, there is also `CGContextAddCurveToPoint` but that is overkill for your implementation here.

If you want more information about Core Graphics then you can find a bunch of documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101